# Spacekey is detected in emulater but i cant detect same event when i run my app on device

Tags: android, keyevent

following are the methods i use to get the key event, which are working fine on emulator but doesn't seem to work on device.

following are the methods i use to get the key event, which are working fine on emulator but doesn't seem to work on device.

```
edTest.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)
            {
                Log.e("keylistner", "keylistner");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    edTest.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)
            {
                Log.e("keylistner", "keylistner");
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)
            {
                Log.e("keylistner", "keylistner");
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getInputType() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content, int states) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)
    {
        Log.e("onkeydown", "onkeydown");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.getKeyCode() ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)
    {
        Log.e("dispatch", "dispatch");
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}



@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.getKeyCode() ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)
    {
        Log.e("onkeyup", "onkeyup");
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```